twisted klein CORS headers not easy to see how to capture preflight OPTIONS call in KLEIN
When Changing from twisted.web to KLEIN for a project, I have run into the problem where I need to deal with the browser preflight request and handle the CORS headers.
But I cannot find any solid information on what to do. It would seem to be a werkzeug issue and I have looked through some of then werkzeug issues and see that the suggestion is to sort it out yourself.
That implies picking out the OPTIONS request within a KLEIN request. I can do that with twisted.web but I'm puzzled as to where to start with KLEIN.
Is it as simple as adding OPTIONS to the list of methods to a route and passing back the requisite headers. This is what I do with twisted.web
I'd be grateful for any clarification

Found out what to do.
Found thread from the bottle framework that discusses the problem and shows me what to do
Bottle Py: Enabling CORS for jQuery AJAX requests

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
